# Top contract by transaction count

Tags: transactions

Is there a list of top contracts on the Ethereum blockchain ordered by the number of transactions that have occurred?

I am looking for a list of popular Ethereum contracts and I am guessing that using the amount of transactions is a good way of determining popularity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fun fact: Cryptokitties has taken the lead: https://ethgasstation.info/gasguzzlers.php

Hope it helps.